# Is it possible to integrate the google test into TFS?

Tags: tfs, googletest

My company has been using the TFS to maintain source codes, tasks and requirements, etc. Also We've made all the test cases using gtest (C++ is heavily used in our company). Now we want to make sure all our requirements are covered by test cases.

So, is it possible to integrate the gtest into the TFS?  By saying that, we want to be able to know how many cases are linked to a requirement (and vice versa), whenever any cases failed, we shall be able to know which requirement is compromised.

Any suggestions will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to VS2012/TFS2012, there is a new extensibility feature that allows 3rd party testing frameworks to be integrated.  It appears someone has made one for gtest.

http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.co.nz/2012/10/gtest-c-unit-testing-test-adapter-for.html

Comment: We are still using VS2010, still thanks anyway, maybe someday not far away we will get the upgrade:)